# react : NPM install fails

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-shrinkwrap

I tried installing a package in my react app using npm, and for some reason It fails:
it shows the following error:

```
npm ERR! Object for dependency "@babel/generator" is empty.
npm ERR! Something went wrong. Regenerate the package-lock.json with "npm install".
npm ERR! If using a shrinkwrap, regenerate with "npm shrinkwrap".
```

I tried npm install to regenerate the package-lock.json but it's the same as before.

Comment: what's your package json like? did you try deleting the package-lock.json + /node_modules and then reinstalling?

Answer (score 15):

#### TLDR

> There is some dependency error with npm, so how about clear project

#### Answer

First of all, How about clear `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`

```
rm -rf ./node_modules package-lock.json
```

and retry install with

`npm install` or `npm i`

and what I want to say is clear `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`. If you'd like to get more information about deleting here is the [link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-remove-files-and-directories-using-linux-command-line/)

Comment: I tried clearing them but it ends up with that error. so I deleted the package-lock.json manually and tried npm install and it worked.

Comment: yes there is missing something (coma or similar) in the script. did delete both manually one by one: first `rm -r node_modules` and then `rm package-lock.json`.

Answer (score 1):

What version of the babel (and it's sub-modules) do you use? Show rows from your package.json file (related to babel).
Your issue possibly could be resolved by updating all babel-related modules

Comment: the ```package.json``` seemed to be fine, so I removed the ```package-lock.json``` and tried ```npm install``` it its solved.

Comment: It may be solved once, but occur again while you install new dependancies.